# How to init public function from theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes

I use Astra theme on a site with WooCommerce. There are a build in Quickview function for the products. I wish only to activate this for a specific category which is not possible on the theme. I do not wish to just hide it with css, so I have located the place where the code origins from in this file: https://developers.wpastra.com/astra-pro/reference/classes/astra_ext_woocommerce_markup/

I tried just to use this:
`add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', array( $this, 'init_quick_view' ), 999 );`

But just got an error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in
..."

Can anyone help or guide me to how to init the function "init_quick_view" in my own functions.php file where I can make my own conditions for when to run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'init_quick_view', 999 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'custom_init_quick_view', 999 );
```

copy `init_quick_view` function into yours `custom_init_quick_view` and add your conditions. Another approach could be

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'init_quick_view', 999 );
if(is_product_category('catslug') {
   add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'init_quick_view', 999 );
}
```

I havent tested. If none of those works ill try to install the theme and test